# How do I get python to automatically create a variable for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance, lets say I have a for loop like this

```
for i in range(7):
   var+i=i
```

How do I get it to work where 7 different variables are created where var0=0 and var1=1 var2=2, etc..

Comment: You shouldn't need that. Use a list.

Comment: Don't do that. Don't dynamically create variables. Use a *container* list a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps use a list `list(range(7))` or  perhaps use `exec('var0=' + i)` to dynamically execute a statement creating a var

Comment: @IronMan no, *don't do that*. Don't use `exec` to dynamically create variables. It is *almost always* a bad design choice

Comment: Agreed @juanpa.arrivillaga!